# String to XML java parse

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have string which contains characters like: č, ć, š, ž etc.

This is code to convert string to xml:

```
public Document convertStringToDocument() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        String xmlStr = new String(getString());
        try  
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(out)));


            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

And i get this error:

[Fatal Error] :6:30: Element type "Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraÃ" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 30; Element type "Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraÃ" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.reports.service.ReportsWS.convertStringToDocument(ReportsWS.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: can you provide xml,it seems that Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraÃ element is not closed properly

Comment: [<Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraćenu_x0020_firmu_x0020_emitenta>Dioničko društvo</Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraćenu_x0020_firmu_x0020_emitenta>]

Comment: it is closed propertly... i know this because i have same tags before this line, but they dont contain characters like ć, č etc...

Comment: can u share full xml.

Comment: when i replace ć with c it works...

Comment: can you do one thing,open the xml in browser and check it open properly or not.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Reports>
  <CO>    <Registarski_x0020_broj_x0020_emitenta_x0020_u_x0020_registru_x0020_kod_x0020_Komisije_x003A_>01</Registarski_x0020_broj_x0020_emitenta_x0020_u_x0020_registru_x0020_kod_x0020_Komisije_x003A_>
    <_x0031_._x0020_PODACI_x0020_O_x0020_IDENTITETU_x0020_EMITENTA />
    <Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraćenu_x0020_firmu_x0020_emitenta>Dioničko društvo</Punu_x0020_i_x0020_skraćenu_x0020_firmu_x0020_emitenta>
</CO></Reports>

Comment: why? it seem ok to me

Comment: whr <Registarski_x0020_broj_x0020_emitenta_x0020_u_x0020_registru_x0020_kod_x0020_Ko??misije_x003A_>01</Registarski_x0020_broj_x0020_emitenta_x0020_u_x0020_registru_x0??020_kod_x0020_Komisije_x003A_> <_x0031_._x0020_PODACI_x0020_O_x0020_IDENTITETU_x0020_EMITENTA />  section is not proper